# Removing Hello Dolly Actually Breaks my Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Well this is new to me, and quite confusing as my curious mind seeks for a resolution. Hello Dolly does **NOT** display as a plugin option in my list of plugins within the wordpress location. Within Cpanel in the plugins folder, "Hello" is the name of the plugin (folder) that exists. If I remove this folder, I then get a notice in my plugin section within wordpress admin that informs me that Hello Dolly has been disabled due to missing files.

The crazy thing is, then my site results in issues like the following:
[image]
[image]

Who would of thought Hello Dolly was so important; what am I missing?

I have since re-added the plugin files and the issues (Notice's) have gone away at: [www.TattiniBoots.com](http://www.TattiniBoots.com). If you would like me to remove Hello Dolly again so that the issues are prevalent, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your database and look at your table wp_options, remove any reference to the Hello Dolly plugin. I had to do this once a few years ago. Sometimes the removal of plugins does not fully work, so you have to go in and purge any excess data.

Comment: This is likely the solution. In fact I remember seeing a few "Remove Hello Dolly" scripts just because of the actual complexity to rid this thing. It's not really a detriment to me given its useless nature, but it is ironic how a site is built on dependency of such a worthless plugin (no offense Dolly)

Comment: Ha yes, I don't think I have ever activated the plugin and have always removed it and Askimet as soon as I get into the dashboard of a build. Most times plugins remove themselves and it's no big deal, but there are cases where they like to hold themselves up in the database and it's just a mess.